# How to select rows from second join table which can be joined on either of 2 columns depending on length of source column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lookup table that has names and corresponding 2 different codes a 9-digit one and a 11-character alpha-numeric one. The rows can be searched based on either of the 2 codes given depending on what the user selected while entering. So depending on whether the user has entered a 9-digit code or a 11-character alphanumeric code, I have to join the lookup table and accurately fetch the name.

Here's an example of the tables

Data table

```
+-----------+------------+
| code      | other cols |
+-----------+------------+
|112111213  | ...        |
|ABCD112233X| ...        |
|           |            |
+-----------+------------+
```

Lookup table

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
|code1    |code2      |name        |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|112111213|XXXX111111Z|Name 1      |
|000000000|ABCD112233X|Name 2      |
|         |           |            |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

How can I get the result like below

```
+-----------+------------+
| code      | name       |
+-----------+------------+
|112111213  | Name 1     |
|ABCD112233X| Name 2     |
|           |            |
+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only either `code1` or `code2` would match in the join, you may try joining with OR logic:

```
UPDATE Data d
INNER JOIN Lookup l
    ON d.code = l.code1 OR d.code = l.code2
SET
    d.name = l.name;
```

Note that the presence of `OR` in the join condition might imply that your `Lookup` table is not properly normalized.  Ideally, it might be better to maintain just a single code lookup column.

**Edit:**

I suggest refactoring your lookup table to the following:

```
+------------+-----------+
|code        |name       |
+------------+-----------+
|112111213   |Name 1     |
|XXXX111111Z |Name 1     |
|000000000   |Name 2     |
|ABCD112233X |Name 2     |
+------------+-----------+
```

Now you may simply perform a single join against the above `code` column and retrieve the `name`, assuming that a match be found.  I am assuming that multiple matches would not occur.  If they could, then you would need to add logic to handle that.

Comment: Note that the presence of OR in the join condition might imply that person doesnt know how to optimize sql queries and use OR instead of UNION, but the output is write - better keep both types of codes in one column if no real reason to keep them separately

Comment: @Tim But how do I normalize when the lookup table itself has 2 different codes for each Name and both codes are valid. Except the the user can use either the 9-digit code or the 11-character alphanumeric one to enter data.

Comment: Put both codes into a single column and then just join once.  This assumes that one and at most one code would match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry didn't follow... How do I put both codes in a single column? It would look like (to take the first lookup table row example) - '112111213XXXX111111Z' and of course this would never match any code from the data table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the edit and the explanation. If I refactor my lookup table itself as you suggest then all the issues are resolved via a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

It can be code like this

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.code1 as code FROM data as t1
INNER JOIN Lookup as t2
    ON t1.code = t2.code1 
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.name, t2.code2 as code FROM data as t1
INNER JOIN Lookup as t2
    ON t1.code = t2.code2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `or` based `join` or you can use two separate query with `union all`.

**Query 1:** or based join

```
SELECT d.code, l.name 
FROM data_table  d
JOIN lookup_table l ON d.code = l.code1 OR d.code = l.code2;
```

**Query 2:** union all based join

```
SELECT d.code, l.name 
FROM data_table  d
JOIN lookup_table l ON d.code = l.code1
UNION ALL
SELECT d.code, l.name 
FROM data_table  d
JOIN lookup_table l ON d.code = l.code2;
```

**Note:** Better use on index use `union` query.

**P.S:** Based on @Tim you need to normalize the table.